# Error 'LoadImage Type' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, emgucv, opencv3.0

I got above error after copying and pasting some `code` from here, [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_Windows_10_Installation_Tutorial/master/CannyStill.vb). 
Will you guys help me to fix it? my code:

```
Imports Emgu.CV                 'usual Emgu Cv imports
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum          '
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure       '
Imports Emgu.CV.UI
Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub btnOpenFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenFile.Click
```

The `LoadImageType` gives me some suggestions, I tried but didn't get helpful.

```
            imgOriginal = New Mat(ofdOpenFile.FileName, LoadImageType.Color)
        Catch ex As Exception                                                       
        CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, imgBlurred, New Size(5, 5), 1.5)
        CvInvoke.Canny(imgBlurred, imgCanny, 100, 200)
        ibOriginal.Image = imgOriginal              'update image boxes
        ibCanny.Image = imgCanny                    '
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is the error:
[image]

[image: These are my project files]

Answer (score 0):

I notice you created your own class called `LoadImageType.vb`. However, `LoadImageType` is already a OpenCV `enum`. You get this error because you probably don't refer to this class at all or you don't initialize it (see also [this link](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_vbnet_name_not_declared.htm)).

I would recommend you to remove this custom class that you created and use the OpenCV `enum`. This `enum` is located in the `Emgu.CV.CvEnum` namespace. Maybe specifically specify you want to use the `CVEnum` namespace:

```
imgOriginal = New Mat(ofdOpenFile.FileName, CvEnum.LoadImageType.Color)
'You can even try this
imgOriginal = New Mat(ofdOpenFile.FileName, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LoadImageType.Color)
```

If this doesn't work, why don't you try to see if you can specifically enter a integer? The `LoadImageType` enum is nothing else then a conversion to a integer (see [docs](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/77593b3f-dda7-51b7-565c-19fd52a2462d.htm)). So for color, you should enter value `1`. If this works, you know something goes wrong with using the enumeration:

```
imgOriginal = New Mat(ofdOpenFile.FileName, 1)
```

If this still doesn't work, why don't you just use the `imread` method (see [docs](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/53904ed8-916c-74ea-40ee-e66a84d87a33.htm))? I always use that one without a `LoadImageType enum` and have no problems at all:

```
Dim img As Mat
img = CvInvoke.Imread(ofdOpenFile.FileName)
```

Or if you specifically want to use `LoadImageType` you can also try:

```
Dim img As Mat
img = CvInvoke.Imread(ofdOpenFile.FileName, CvEnum.LoadImageType.Color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Six years later but can be of help to somebody. Simply replace
LoadImageType.Color
for:
CType(1, ImreadModes)
As said by @Jurjen, it's an integer only, BUT comes from ImreadModes enum.